# Can't download anything on Debian 12

Tags: debian

Every time I try to download something; both via terminal or GUI app, it says
"Media change :please insert the disc labeled
'Debian GNU/Linux 12.1.0_Bookworm_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 with firmware 20230722-10:49' in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter]"

Answer (score 4):

Remove the cdrom entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Here is the default config for bookworm (Debian 12):

```bash
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main
```

If this does not solve the problem, please give us your `sources.list` so we may help you.