# Cant apt update on Debian 12

Tags: debian, upgrade

When trying to do sudo apt update/upgrade i get faced with

```
E: Malformed entry 3 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_deb_debian_org_debian-bookworm.list (Component)
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_deb_debian_org_debian_bookworm-bookworm.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

This error started happening after i tried to follow another post on here ([Can't download anything on Debian 12](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/752881/cant-download-anything-on-debian-12)) because after opening my fresh install of Debian i couldn't install any new software being faced with the error
`Media change :please insert the disc labeled 'Debian GNU/Linux 12.1.0_Bookworm_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 with firmware 20230722-10:49' in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter]`
i cleared my souces.list file and only added

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main
```

anything is helpful i'm new to debian and linux all together if someone can point me in the right direction for resources or just help me out with this it would be helpful :)

Comment: so, as your error says, your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_deb_debian_org_debian-bookworm.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_deb_debian_org_debian_bookworm-bookworm.list` are broken, not the `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: The question is why you *have* these in the first place. Did you put them there? Or do you have an idea what might have put them there? On a fresh debian 12 installation, they do not exist.

Comment: @MarcusMüller after I fresh installed Debian I wanted to download other software but it was giving me "Media change :please insert the disc labeled 'Debian GNU/Linux 12.1.0_Bookworm_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 with firmware 20230722-10:49' in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter]" trying to fix this i followed https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/752881/cant-download-anything-on-debian-12 and now i've gotten myself in this situation

Comment: That is (if you think about it, quite intuitively) important information to someone that tries to help you. Can you add that to your question by *editing* it?

Comment: Can't see how following https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/752881/cant-download-anything-on-debian-12 could have led to the creation of the files archive_uri-http_deb_debian_org_debian-bookworm.list or archive_uri-http_deb_debian_org_debian_bookworm-bookworm.list which don't appear in that Q/A. Maybe some graphical tool editing apt repositories would have done it?

Comment: I have edited my post all i did was add those three sources and it lead to this

Comment: "i cleared my souces.list file and only added" **Which** file specifically did you "clear"? How did you do that? You just said you couldn't access the file, so that makes no sense.

Comment: You have to provide the content of the additional files described in the error messages. results of `ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d`, and then *probably* (you must adapt to the situation) `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_deb_debian_org_debian-bookworm.list` + `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_deb_debian_org_debian_bookworm-bookworm.list`

Comment: @A.B running ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d lists out
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 100 Nov  6 11:26 archive_uri-http_deb_debian_org_debian_bookworm-bookworm.list
 and 6 other similar ones should i change the cat command to cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_deb_debian_org_debian_bookworm-bookworm.list?

Comment: [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/760781/edit). The goal is to provide their content, by whatever mean you prefer.